# After split multiple rows save in SQL Server by while loop

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the stored procedure to insert.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_SaveMail]
     @Subject NVARCHAR(550), 
     @Message NVARCHAR(550),  
     @ParentID INT,  
     @SenderID INT, 
     @SenderType INT, 
     @ReceiverID NVARCHAR(MAX), 
     @ReceiverType INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MailID INT

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Mail] (Subject, Message, ParentID, IsRead, IsDeleted)
    VALUES (@Subject, @Message, @ParentID, 0, 0)

    SET @MailID = (SELECT @@identity)

    if (@MailID > 0)
       -- After this I want to split the @ReceiverID 
       -- The code to split the @ReceiverID is [dbo].SplitString(@ReceiverID, ',')

       -- After split I want to insert it into the table [dbo].[tbl_Mail_Mapping] one by one through for loop or while loop.
   -- BEGIN
   -- DECLARE @tags NVARCHAR(400)

   -- SET @tags = ([dbo].SplitString(@ReceiverID, ','))
   -- WHILE LEN(@tags) > 0
   -- BEGIN
   --     INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Mail_Mapping](MailID, SenderID, SenderType, ReceiverID, ReceiverType)
   --     VALUES (@MailID, @SenderID, @SenderType, @tags, @ReceiverType) 
   -- END
END
```

Here is the code to split:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
    (@Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @Character CHAR(1))
RETURNS @Output TABLE (Item NVARCHAR(1000))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT

    SET @StartIndex = 1

    IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
    BEGIN
        SET @Input = @Input + @Character
    END

    WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

        INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

        SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
    END

    RETURN
END
```

Can anyone tell me how I can write a while loop after split and insert query to insert into table?

Note: `@ReceiverID` looks like this: `3,2,5` i.e. Here I split the `@ReceiverID` through a call to `[dbo].SplitString(@ReceiverID, ',')`. After split it returns like a table with column items 3 2 5

Refer to this screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRfR3.png)

After split can anyone tell me how to write the while loop to save??

Comment: After split how can i use the while loop...to save the data??

Comment: **Typo** alert - it's a **receiver** - "e" before "i" (not a "reciever" ....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a loop. Use SELECT from your table-valued function:

```sql
INSERT INTO  [dbo].[tbl_Mail_Mapping]( MailID, SenderID, SenderType, RecieverID, RecieverType )
SELECT   @MailID
        ,@SenderID
        ,@SenderType
        ,r.Item
        ,@RecieverType
FROM [dbo].[SplitString](@RecieverID, ',') r
WHERE Item != ''
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i think you don't need to use while loop or function, you could do that simply by using `XML` Method as below :

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[tbl_Mail_Mapping]
(MailID,
 SenderID,
 SenderType,
 RecieverID,
 RecieverType
)
       SELECT @MailID,
              @SenderID,
              @SenderType,
              split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
              @RecieverType
       FROM
       (
           SELECT CAST('<M>'+REPLACE(@RecieverID, ',', '</M><M>')+'</M>' AS XML) AS Data
       ) r
       CROSS APPLY Data.nodes('/M') split(a)
       WHERE split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') != '';
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[tbl_Mail_Mapping];
```

Comment: can you write down a proper format for the above query

Comment: In [dbo].[tbl_Mail_Mapping] i have enter the multiple column..you just look my question code.